# Wordpress in its own directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a recent install of WP 3.9.2, from InMotion.
I'm using the instructions at this url to put the wordpress files in their own directory, not in the root for my site:

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
```

I've used this before, and it worked.

This time, these instructions to change the index.php file:

```
Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says:

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

don't make sense because there is no "require" line with the "/wp-blog-header.php" file name.

The only require lines in the new index.php file are these:

```
/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */

require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );

/** Load WordPress dashboard API */

require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php');
```

I tried adding my designated wp folder to these, but no joy.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong `index.php` — What you posted fits `<root>/wp-admin/index.php`, or, maybe `<root>/wp-admin/network/index.php`.

The file referenced in the documentation is `<root>/index.php` where `<root>` is the top-most folder of the current WordPress install.

It should look like this when you open it:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

*(I've checked by downloading a fresh 3.9.2)*

If you can't find the correct `index.php`, try searching for `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` via the built-in search function of your OS.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for checking it out thoroughly.  I followed the instructions *properly* and it works as described.  Gracie!

Comment: @wayfarer No problem — We've all been there :)